How to set up CMakeLists.txt for Libtorch in a C++ Project?
I have a simple project with use of libtorch. The structure of the project is the following:
MyLibtorchProject/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── libtorch/
└── build/ 

The content of CMakeLists.txt is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyLibtorchProject)

# Set the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

# Set the LibTorch directory path
set(Torch_DIR "C:/Desktop/Audio_C++_JUCE/MyLibtorchProject/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")

# Find the LibTorch package
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# Add the executable target
add_executable(MyLibtorchProject main.cpp)

# Link LibTorch to your executable
target_link_libraries(MyLibtorchProject "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

# Ensure the target uses C++17 features
target_compile_features(MyLibtorchProject PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

# Set the C++ flags required by LibTorch
set_property(TARGET MyLibtorchProject PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_property(TARGET MyLibtorchProject PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Set debug and release configurations if needed
if (MSVC)
  # Enable multithreading and increase the number of sections in object files
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP /bigobj /std:c++17")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -std=c++17")
endif()

And, the main.cpp is:
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Create a simple tensor
    torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
    std::cout << "Tensor:\n" << tensor << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I have run cmake as followed
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/Desktop/Audio_C++_JUCE/MyLibtorchProject/libtorch" .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

then, I have built the MyLibtorchProject project with success. But when I run it, I encountered the following:
The procedure entry point
?at_Half_metadata_index@detail@caffe2@@3GB could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Desktop\Audio_C++_JUCE\MyLibtorchProject\build\Debug\MyLibtorchProject.exe

I have introduced in the PATH Sytem C:\Desktop\Audio_C++_JUCE\MyLibtorchProject\libtorch
So, what am I missing?

This doesn't seem like a path problem. It seems to be an incompatible binaries problem. Like the libraries you are using aren't compatible with your compiler or you are mixing versions.

Unrelated: the /std:c++17 and -std=c++17 flags are not necessary since you have already asked CMake for C++17 twice at that point.
